# Assigning Values to properties in Structures

Tags: vb.net

In the below code "f" is an instance of the Class FORM which has a property "s" of type SIZE, a structure which has been defined in the code. My question is: When I try to assign values to the attributes of property "s" of the instance "t" directly it does not work: That is the statement `f.s.height = 15` does not work. My confusion is arising from the fact that when I print the values of the property "s" of the instance "f", I am able to print the individual attributes of the structure SIZE but the same cannot be done while assignment of value. Assignment of values require me to call the constructor. Why is it so? What is preventing the assignment of the value to the attributes of "s": i.e. f.s.height & f.s.width?

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim f As New MyForm()
        f.s = New Size(2, 5) 'Works Fine
        f.colour = "Red"  'Assignment works just fine

        'Below: Individual elements cannot be acceessed for assignment. WHY?
        f.s.height = 15   'Doesn't Work
        f.s.height = +2   'Doesn't work

        'Individual elements can be accessed while printing
        Console.WriteLine("Widht = {0}", f.s.width)
        Console.WriteLine("Height = {0}", f.s.height)

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
Class MyForm
    Public Property s As Size
    Public Property colour As String
End Class

Public Structure Size
    Dim height As Integer
    Dim width As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal w As Integer, ByVal h As Integer)
        width = w
        height = h
    End Sub
End Structure
```

Pls help.

Comment: In `f.s` your Size struct (bad name) is returned by value, so you're trying to assign a new value to a member that is not retained after the assignment. Use a class instead (with a different name), or a assign a new struct to the property.

Comment: @Jimi can u pls elaborate on the meaning of "f.s. is returned by value"? Not understanding what it means? Also what do you mean when u say "member that is not retained after the assignment"?

Comment: @Sougata Does [Parameter passing in C#](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html) help?

Comment: Your Size is a struct, a ValueType: when you read it, it returns a copy. So, you can read the value, change it and assign it, as in: `dim s1 = Me.s s1.height = 200 Me.s = s1` or just `Me.s = new Size(Me.s.width, 200)`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler should be indicating "*Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment*".

Change `Size` from a `Structure` to a `Class` (and `Dim` to `Property`) to fix the problem:

```
Public Class Size
    Property height As Integer
    Property width As Integer
    Public Sub New(w As Integer, h As Integer)
        width = w
        height = h
    End Sub
End Class
```

By the way, you'll also see this behaviour with the standard `System.Drawing.Size` which is defined as a `Structure` rather than a `Class`. (So is `Point` and probably others.)

Comment: you are absolutely right with your error statement. But i do not want to change the structure to a class. I want to understand WHY the compiler gives the error? The reason I want to understand this is because this is precisely the problem when I use the SIZE property of the FORM class to define its size. If i need to alter the height and width of the form using the SIZE property I need to call the constructor. I would not be allowed to individually set the attributes, i.e. i cant write form.size.height = 500 in the same way i cant write here f.s.height = 15. The question is WHY?

Comment: @Sougata I think it's a good question. You can change it directly, say if you define a size object independent of the Form object, but when it's "embedded" as a property of the Form object you can't. I don't have an answer for you on that front, but someone with a deeper knowledge of the internals will know ... give it 5 min I'd say!

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is fundamental to value types (`Structure`s).  Conceptually, an instance of a value type is supposed to represent a single immutable value, and any instances with the same value are all supposed to be equivalent.  As you have observed, you can get very surprising behavior if you try to change parts of an existing value type.  It's really not intended for you to be able to alter them piecewise.

For this reason, I will always recommend that the members of a value type should be marked as `ReadOnly` so that you get blocked from trying to change them after construction.

If you want to be able to treat something like a mutable object instance instead of an immutable value, it needs to be a reference type (a `Class`).  That's what they're designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching I came across the following article which probably explains the reason why we are not able to directly access the height/width attribute of the SIZE structure through an instance of the FORM class. Requesting people to go through this as the author has given a lot of details:

http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

PLs feel free to share any difference in opinion.